# Ebpf: Copy variable length data to a map in 4.14 kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf

I am tracing `read()` system call using EBPF on a 4.14 kernel. This code works fine on later kernels, however, the verifier rejects this on 4.14.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

#define MIN(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))

struct read_enter_ctx {
        unsigned long long unused;
        int __syscall_nr;
        //unsigned int padding;
        unsigned long fd;
        char* buf;
        size_t count;
};

struct read_exit_ctx {
        unsigned long long unused;
        int __syscall_nr;
        long ret;
};


struct {
        __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY);
        __uint(max_entries, 1);
        __type(key, int);
        __type(value, void*);
} saved_read_ctx SEC(".maps");

#define HEAP_BUFFER_SIZE (2 * 1024)

struct heap_buffer {
        char buf[HEAP_BUFFER_SIZE];
};

/* This is the temporary storage - 'heap', used to copy userspace buffers */
struct {
        __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY);
        __uint(max_entries, 1);
        __type(key, int);
        __type(value, struct heap_buffer);
} heap SEC(".maps");

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_read")
int trace_read_enter(struct read_enter_ctx *ctx)
{
        int zero = 0;
        void *p = ctx->buf;

        bpf_map_update_elem(&saved_read_ctx, &zero, &p, BPF_ANY);
        return 0;
}

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_exit_read")
int trace_read_exit(struct read_exit_ctx *ctx)
{
        char *map_buf;
        void **ubuf;
        int zero = 0;
        unsigned long min;

        ubuf = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&saved_read_ctx, &zero);
        if (!ubuf)
                return 0;

        if (ctx->ret <= 0)
                return 0;

        map_buf = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&heap, &zero);
        if (!map_buf) {
                return 0;
        }

        min = MIN(ctx->ret, HEAP_BUFFER_SIZE);
        min &= 0xffff;
        //min = 16;  // verifier is happy once I uncomment this line
#if 1

        // this is where things go bad
        if (bpf_probe_read_user(map_buf, min, *ubuf)) {
                return 0;
        }
#endif
        return 0;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

```
WARNING: libbpf: prog 'trace_read_exit': BPF program load failed: Permission denied

WARNING: libbpf: prog 'trace_read_exit': -- BEGIN PROG LOAD LOG --
0: (bf) r7 = r1
1: (b7) r1 = 0
2: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -4) = r1
3: (bf) r2 = r10
4: (07) r2 += -4
5: (18) r1 = 0xffff888804364200
7: (85) call bpf_map_lookup_elem#1
8: (bf) r6 = r0
9: (15) if r6 == 0x0 goto pc+18
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R6=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R7=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
10: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r7 +16)
11: (b7) r2 = 1
12: (6d) if r2 s> r1 goto pc+15
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R1=inv(id=0,umin_value=1,umax_value=9223372036854775807,var_off=(0x0; 0x7fffffffffffffff)) R2=inv1 R6=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R7=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
13: (bf) r2 = r10
14: (07) r2 += -4
15: (18) r1 = 0xffff888804364700
17: (85) call bpf_map_lookup_elem#1
18: (15) if r0 == 0x0 goto pc+9
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=2048,imm=0) R6=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R7=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
19: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r7 +16)
20: (bf) r2 = r1
21: (57) r2 &= 65535
22: (b7) r3 = 2048
23: (6d) if r3 s> r1 goto pc+1
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=2048,imm=0) R1=inv(id=0,umin_value=2048,umax_value=9223372036854775807,var_off=(0x0; 0x7fffffffffffffff)) R2=inv(id=0,umax_value=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff)) R3=inv2048 R6=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R7=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
24: (b7) r2 = 2048
25: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r6 +0)
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=2048,imm=0) R1=inv(id=0,umin_value=2048,umax_value=9223372036854775807,var_off=(0x0; 0x7fffffffffffffff)) R2=inv2048 R3=inv2048 R6=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R7=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
26: (bf) r1 = r0
27: (85) call bpf_probe_read#4
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=2048,imm=0) R1=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=2048,imm=0) R2=inv2048 R3=inv(id=0) R6=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R7=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
28: (b7) r0 = 0
29: (95) exit

from 23 to 25: R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=2048,imm=0) R1=inv(id=0,smax_value=2047) R2=inv(id=0,umax_value=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff)) R3=inv2048 R6=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R7=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
25: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r6 +0)
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=2048,imm=0) R1=inv(id=0,smax_value=2047) R2=inv(id=0,umax_value=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff)) R3=inv2048 R6=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R7=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
26: (bf) r1 = r0
27: (85) call bpf_probe_read#4
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=2048,imm=0) R1=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=2048,imm=0) R2=inv(id=0,umax_value=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff)) R3=inv(id=0) R6=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R7=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
invalid access to map value, value_size=2048 off=0 size=0
R1 min value is outside of the array range
-- END PROG LOAD LOG --

WARNING: libbpf: failed to load program 'trace_read_exit'
```

How do I make this work for 4.14 kernels? Looking through the 4.14 verifier code, this is where the code breaks. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.248/source/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L1016

Comment: On what kernels did you test this? I think you will need Linux commit https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bpf/bpf.git/commit/?id=d71962f3e627.

Comment: @pchaigno
I tried this on 4.14.248. Interestingly, the map access works fine if the size argument to `bpf_probe_read_user()` is a constant. See the the code 
```
min = 16 // verifier is happy once I uncomment this line
```
Did you mean this commit? https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/netdev/net-next.git/commit/?id=5722569bb9c3bd922c4f10b5b2912fe88c255312

Comment: @pchaigno On 4.14, `bpf_probe_read()` helper `arg2` is of `ARG_CONST_SIZE` unlike 4.15 where arg2 is `ARG_CONST_SIZE_OR_ZERO`. On 4.14, I have to additionally convince the verifier that `R2` minimum value is greater than zero. It looks like this is where I am failing.
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.248/source/kernel/trace/bpf_trace.c#L80